# i'm trying to delete the item from the List view, data is fetched from an API

Tags: flutter, android-listview, flutter-dependencies

here is code I have been used, when using Dismissible to delete the items the code is throwing error "type string is not subtype of type int of index "

```
  Widget getBody(item){
    var fullName = item['first_name']+" "+item['last_name'];
    var email = item['email'];
    var profileUrl = item['avatar'];
    if(users.contains(null) || users.length < 0 || isLoading){
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          // return getCard(users[index]);
          return Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
            onDismissed: (_){
              setState(() {
                users.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
           
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```